# How to calculate the probability of each columns in DataFrame -using R (Assuming Normal Distribution)

Tags: r

This is my DF:

```
   Con1   Con2   Con3   Con4
1   45    576
2   23    1234
3   67    345
4   22     44
5   5      567
```

I want for each column to find the Mean and the SD.
Then for each cell in the specific column I want to apply Normal distribution calculation to find the probability for each cell's number in specific column.
For example, Con1's mean are 32.4 and SD 4, I want to take each number in this column and apply normal distribution to find the probability for each number - and then replace the number with its probability.

the output (For example):

```
  Con1     Con2     Con3   Con4
1   0.6    0.455
2   0.34    0.09
3   0.23    0.12
4   0.1     0.55
5   0.7     0.88
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

In base R you can do this with...

```
sapply(df, function(x) pnorm(x, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))

          Con1      Con2
[1,] 0.7002401 0.5207649
[2,] 0.3476271 0.9400139
[3,] 0.9253371 0.3172112
[4,] 0.3323590 0.1224208
[5,] 0.1267551 0.5125718
```

This uses `pnorm`, which is the cumulative normal distribution function. If you want the density instead, use `dnorm`.  You might also like to have a look at the `scale` function to normalise values.